# content gets hidden while using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using ajax for fetching records using following code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.go-btn').on('click', function() {
        var selected = $('#my-dropdown option:selected');
            $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
        type: "GET",
        url: "boxplot.html",             
        dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
        success: function(response){                    
            $("#responsecontainer").html(response); 
            //alert(response);
        }

    });
        //alert(selected.val()); 
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

some text
<button class="go-btn" type="submit">Go</button> 
<div id="responsecontainer">
<br><hr><br>
<h2>PCA Plot Distribution:</h2><br>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above code, content page gets loaded on clicking button (at ) but anything after this gets disappeared. How can i fix this issue?

Comment: Use `append` instead of `html` method. You are replacing contents every time you call that AJAX.

Comment: Did you try: `$("#responsecontainer").html(response.d); `

Answer (score 1):

Because you are setting your response to whole div. Fix your html such that

```
<div id="responsecontainer"></div> 
<div>
<br><hr><br>
<h2>PCA Plot Distribution:</h2><br>
</div>
```

So you are settings your response to `responsecontainer` and rest remains same.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't closed your `div` in the HTML in the bottom

Answer (score 0):

You just have to close that #responsecontainer div.

```js
var response = "my Response";
$("#goButton").on("click", function(){
  $("#responsecontainer").html(response);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>

some text
<button class="go-btn" type="submit" id="goButton">Go</button> 
<div id="responsecontainer"></div>
<br><hr><br>
<h2>PCA Plot Distribution:</h2><br>
</body>
</html>
```